# Using Piecewise to plot a defined function

Tags: plotting, functions, piecewise, intervals

I'm trying to Plot this function:

[image]

Between the interval -0.2 < t < 0.1 but it doesn't work. All i get is a blank graph between my intervals. If you could help me out I'd greatly appreciate it.

This is my code:

```
Plot[Piecewise[{{Sqrt[t]*Sin[t^(-1)], x > 0}, {t*Sin[t^(-1)]}}], {t, -0.2, 0.1}]
```

Comment: 1. The `x` should be `t`. 2. Syntax of `Piecewise` is wrong, please check the document of `Piecewise` for more information. The correct one should be `Plot[Piecewise[{{Sqrt[t] Sin[1/t], 
         t > 0}}, t Sin[1/t]], 
   {t, -0.2, 0.1}]`

Comment: Oh my god. I've been spending way to much in front of the computer today it seems. I don't know what I was thinking when I put x instead of t.

Comment: No problem. These things happen to all of us. Anyways, since this is settled, I vote to close this post as "simple mistake".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the function is only defined at `t == 0` in the limit and the [`Limit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Limit.html) is `0`, you want to specify both conditions in the [`Piecewise`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html) and let its default cover the limiting case.

```
Limit[Sqrt[t]*Sin[t^(-1)], t -> 0] == Limit[t*Sin[t^(-1)], t -> 0] == 0

(* True *)

Manipulate[
 Plot[
  Piecewise[{
    {Sqrt[t]*Sin[t^(-1)], t > 0},
    {t*Sin[t^(-1)], t < 0}}],
  {t, xmin, xmax},
  Frame -> True,
  FrameTicks -> All,
  WorkingPrecision -> 20,
  PlotPoints -> 200,
  MaxRecursion -> 10,
  PlotStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[0.5]],
 {{xmin, -0.2}, -0.2, -0.02, 0.02, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{xmax, 0.1}, 0.02, 0.1, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 SynchronousUpdating -> False]
```

[image]